# Finding sequence starting from a particular number in Big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, netezza

How can we achieve the same functionality as of 'SEQUENCE' in provided in Netezza?

Please find below the link demonstrating the functionality I would like to achieve in Big query :

[https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_create_sequence.html][1]

I have reviewed RANK() but this is not solving my purpose to the core. Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in BigQuery Standard SQL you can find two function that can help you here -

[`GENERATE_ARRAY(start_expression, end_expression\[, step_expression\])`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_array)

and

[`GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date\[, INTERVAL INT64_expr date_part\])`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_date_array)

For example, below code

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT sequence
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 10, 1)) AS sequence
```

produces result as

```sql
sequence     
1    
2    
3    
4    
5    
6    
7    
8    
9    
10
```

Comment: Thank you for these solutions. In my actual scenario I have to produce the column values from any table with an incremental sequence. For example : If there are 2 records to be produced from a table having columns 'name' and 'color' then it would be like --- [1,Balajee,Red],[2,Mikhail,Blue] where you can see the first column is following an incremental sequence starting with '1'. Using these functions I tried to implement the same but couldn't achieve the same. Any workaround?

Comment: from what you explain in your comment - it sounds quite simple  - but there is no way to give you specific answer as it is still too broad! as I recommended already  - you should ask new question with your bery specific example - instead of asking generic question - that of course gives you still relevant but generic answer